# IE8 Compatibility Mode not working - debugging

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ie8-compatibility-mode, respond.js

I am building a responsive infographic using media queries and respond.js.

Everything is working fine until I get down to IE8 with compatibility mode turned on and for some reason my navigation disappears and it seems like *some* media queries have stopped working.

Does anyone have a good way to debug IE8 while using browser stack - for some reason firebug lite is saying I don't have any styling on this content.

Comment: IE8 with Compatibility Mode is IE7.

Comment: the IE developer toolbar has reasonable debugging http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: just set a proper doctype to your HTML to cross out the chances IE8 will switch to compatibility mode.